# Eclipse - Wrapped lines' indentation appears & disappears each time I save

Tags: java, eclipse, coding-style, formatter, eclipse-jdt

Each time I click `Save` the entire file's formatting alternates between these two formats:

```
this.getObject()
        .method()
        .method();
this.method(arg1, arg2,
        arg3, arg4);
```

and

```
this.getObject()
.method()
.method();
this.method(arg1, arg2,
arg3, arg4);
```

I want it to stick to the first format.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have the same problem with my current Eclipse configuration. I think it is an Eclipse bug.

My guess is that the problem is somewhat related to the option:

```
Java Code Style -> Cleanup -> Code organizing -> Correct indentation
```

getting in conflict with

```
Java Code Style -> Cleanup -> Code organizing -> Format source code
```

which should already fix indentation according to formatter settings.

I disabled the option `Correct indentation` in both `Java Code Style -> Cleanup` and `Java Editor -> Save Actions -> Additional Actions -> Configure...` and the problem seemed to disappear.

Comment: This didn't help in my case. Any idea if the `Check: Remove trailing whitespace / Radio: All lines` could be the culprit

Answer (score 0):

You may have to correct your existing code format from

```
Eclipse preferences > Java > code style > Formatter
```

Or if the current formatter is messing up,  you could uncheck the auto formatting option during save using

```
Eclipse preferences > Java > Editor > Save Actions - UnCheck Format source code.
```

Comment: I want the formatter. Once formatted, there is no reason it should change each time I re-save the exact same file.